# Terraform -- Is possible take a value from a map and put this value inside to a local variable?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I am trying to take a value from a map and I need to put that value inside to a local variable, but I dont know How to do that, I need that because I created multiples lambdas, and some lambdas needs this resource "aws_lambda_permission" and ohters lambdas doesnt need that, I am using the value "method_path" from the map.

variables.tf

```
### Global variables ###
variable "stack_id" {
  type = string
}
variable "vpc_id" {
  type = string
}

### Lambda variables ###
variable "lambda_function" {
  type = map(object({
    memory_size = number
    runtime     = string
    handler     = string
    s3_key      = string
    role        = string
    layers      = optional(list(string))
    method_path = string
    env_key = map(any)

  }))
}
```

main.tf (lambdas)

```
locals {
  add_method_path = var.lambda_function.test-01.method_path
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lm" {
  for_each      = var.lambda_function_l3
  s3_bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.lm.id
  s3_key        = "code/${each.value.s3_key}"
  function_name = "lm-${var.stack_id}-${each.key}"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lm[each.value.role].arn
  handler       = "index.${each.value.handler}"
  runtime       = each.value.runtime
  memory_size   = each.value.memory_size
layers = each.value.layer1 == "null" ? null :aws_lambda_layer_version.lm[each.value.layer1].arn 
  depends_on = [ aws_lambda_layer_version.lm ]
  environment {
    variables = each.value.env_key
  }
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [local.subnet_private[0], local.subnet_private[5]]
    security_group_ids = ["sg-0591b309a73f15dd4"]
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lmp" {
  for_each = local.add_method_path != "false" ? var.lambda_function : {}
  //statement_id  = "AllowMyDemoAPIInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lm[each.key].function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  # The /* part allows invocation from any stage, method and resource path
  # within API Gateway.
  source_arn = "${var.ag_id}/*${each.value.method_path}"
```

terraform.tfvars

```
lambda_function = {
  "test-01" = { memory_size = 512, runtime = "python3.9", handler = "lambda_handler", s3_key = "test_lm.zip", role = "s3_rw",method_path = "/POST/fincor/pucs/depurated/checks", layers = ["capa-openpyxl-s3fs-xlrd-fsspec"], env_key = { house = "car", test2 = "apple" } }
"test-02" = { memory_size = 1024, runtime = "python3.9", handler = "lambda_handler", s3_key = "test_lmv2.zip", role = "dba_r_sec_r", method_path = "false", layers = null, env_key = { window = "bread", test4 = "chicken" } }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin the code doesn’t has errors, I need to put the value "method_path"(variable lambda_function(map) inside to local variable “add_method_path”, because I use “add_method_path” to create the resource "aws_lambda_permission" if the lambdas needs permission, or if the lambdas doesn’t need permission that doesn’t create nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In case your main concern is iterating over the map, you should not even use a local variable

In this case, your solution would be something like this in my opinion:

```hcl
  for_each = { for key, value in var.lambda_function : key => value if value.method_path != "false" }
```

Here, `for_each` is looping through the map `var.lambda_function`, and for each key-value pair, it is assigning the key to the key and the value to the value (key => value), but only if `value.method_path` does not equal `false`.

Using this in your code will result in creating a resource for each of the map's key-value pairs, except when the value (which is an object) has `false` for the property `method_path`.

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

### In case you want to use a local variable

Your code actually works for using the value from a map property as a local variable.

### How did I get here:

1. I took your code and removed everything which is not needed to debug the "local.add_method_path" variable.

main.tf

```hcl
variable "lambda_function" {
  type = map(object({
    method_path = string
  }))
}

locals {
  add_method_path = var.lambda_function.test-01.method_path
}

output "result" {
  value = local.add_method_path
}
```

test.tfvars

```hcl
lambda_function = {
  "test-01" = { 
    method_path = "/POST/fincor/pucs/depurated/checks" 
  }
  "test-02" = { 
    method_path = "false"
  }  
}
```

2. I ran the `terraform plan -var-file="test.tfvars"` to show what the output variable named "result" would be, which is depending on the local variable we are debugging. The result shows what we would expect:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + result = "/POST/fincor/pucs/depurated/checks"
```

Comment: Yes the code works, but only takes a value of the key “test-01”, I am using a conditional in the resource "aws_lambda_permission", because I have some lambdas that needs permission and  others lambdas doesn’t need permission, and I’m trying to use that condition for create or not create permission if the lambdas needs permission, and each key is a lambda.

Comment: I'm suspicious that you will need to rephrase your question. If you do that, I'll do my best to answer it. What you ask is if you can use a value from a map in a local variable, but in the comments you seem to be surprised that that exact value is returned. If you want to iterate multiple objects in the map, you will need to use the for_each or similar command, and not a local variable. The whole point of the local variable in this case would be to extract an exact value, and not to iterate over them.

Comment: @Jefraibo I added another answer which might be closer to what you want

Comment: @Jefraibo can you review my second answer please? I think that will solve your problem